# User coming from a notification click

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications

I want to trigger a Toast if the user come from a Notification click.

But I don't know how to know if a user is coming from a notification click.
Right know I set the notification like that:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

        NotificationChannel channel =
                new NotificationChannel(notification_channel, notification_channel, importance);

        String description = "A channel which shows notifications about the app";
        channel.setDescription(description);

        channel.setLightColor(Color.MAGENTA);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    String notificationTitle = "Title";
    String notificationText = "Notification Text";

    Intent intent_not = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home_Base.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent_not, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //build the notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), notification_channel)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.fiamma)
                    .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                    .setContentText(notificationText)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    //trigger the notification
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());

    notificationManager.notify(123, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting action (say, On_NOTIFICATION_CLICK) using intent_not.setAction()

In  Home_Base using getIntent().getAction(), try to get the action from the intent received.

If the action received in Home_Base is On_NOTIFICATION_CLICK then its a notification Click action.